# Determining length and position of character repeats in string

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

Assume a string `s` that may contain several adjacent occurrences of dashes. For the sake of simplicity, let's call each of these occurrences a "repeat motive". For example, the following string `s` contains five repeat motives of dashes, namely of length 3,2,6,5 and 1.

```
s = "abcde---fghij--klmnopq------rstuvw-----xy-z"
```

I am trying to come up with Python code that returns the respective length and the respective position within the string of each of the repeat motives. Preferentially, the code returns a list of tuples, with each tuple being of format (length, position).

```
sought_function(s)
# [(3,5), (2,13), (6,22), (5,34), (1,41)]
```

Would you have any suggestions as to how to start this code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `groupby`:

```
s = "abcde---fghij--klmnopq------rstuvw-----xy-z"
from itertools import groupby
[(next(g)[0], sum(1 for _ in g) + 1) for k, g in groupby(enumerate(s), lambda x: x[1]) if k == "-"]
# [(5, 3), (13, 2), (22, 6), (34, 5), (41, 1)]
```

---

Or as @Willem commented, replace the `sum` with `len`:

```
[(next(g)[0], len(list(g)) + 1) for k, g in groupby(enumerate(s), lambda x: x[1]) if k == "-"]
# [(5, 3), (13, 2), (22, 6), (34, 5), (41, 1)]
```

Comment: cant you use `len(..)` here instead of `sum(...)`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes I think `len(...)` will also work.

Comment: @Psidom Wow! I had brooded over that question for an hour prior to deciding to post. Thanks for the quick answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write your own function: simply iterate over the characters, and hold in memory the current length, if the sequence is cut off, you yield the element:

```
def find_sequences(s,to_find):
    result = []
    lng = 0
    for i,c in enumerate(s):
        if c == to_find:
            lng += 1
        else:
            if lng:
                result.append((lng,i-lng))
            lng = 0
    if lng:
        result.append((lng,i-lng))
    return result
```

so `s` is the string and `to_find` is the character you are interested in (here `'-'`).

Answer (score 0):

if using numpy is fine :

```
import numpy as np
a = "abcde---fghij--klmnopq------rstuvw-----xy-z"
bool_vec = np.array([letter == "-" for letter in a])
dots = np.where(np.diff(bool_vec)!=0)[0] + 1
number = np.diff(dots.reshape((-1,2)),1).ravel()
idx = dots[::2]
```

with `number` and `idx` two arrays that contain what you want :)

Comment: you can take this one step further and zip the two lists together `zip(number, idx)`

Answer (score 0):

You could do `re.split("(-+)", s)` which will return a list of ["abcde", "---", ...], and then iterate over that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is would be my suggestion for this:

```
import re
s = "abcde---fghij--klmnopq------rstuvw-----xy-z"
list1= []
for x in re.findall("[a-z]*-", s):
    temp = x.strip("-")
    if len(temp) > 0:
        list1.append(temp)
print(list1)
```